# Get ALL certificates installed in a Windows 2003 box

Tags: windows, certificate

It seems that one of our Servers has a certificate that has expired, unfortunately we cannot find it, in other words, it's not in the local machine store or any of the personal stores of any of the support staff or any of the domain accounts currently in use.

Is there a way to list all and mean all certificates of all stores in windows 2003.

Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:

Does not work as it only retrieves the user and the local machine.

There are umpteen service accounts and quite a few potential domain accounts, so using the management console is not really an option.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: What was the cert for?  What broke?

Comment: I was trying to find that out, i.e. what was the cert for, nothing broke. it was just highlighted as part of pen testing.

Comment: Open a command prompt at the root of the drive with the certs and type 'dir *.cer .pk7 /s' without the quotes, and replacing/adding filetypes as needed.